# Object iteration in typescript

Tags: typescript

Why this returns undefined? Even when I give timeObject type any, it still doesnt work.

```
const timeObject = {
  'On web close': 0,
    '10 secconds': 10000,
    '8 hours': 28800000,
    '12 hours': 43200000
}

 let timeToString = (time: number) => {
  Object.keys(timeObject).map((key) => {
    if (timeObject[key] === time) {
      return timeObject[key]
    }
  })
}

console.log(timeToString(10000))
```

Comment: I have posted the answer, please check

Comment: If this answers your question, please mark it as answered

Comment: I know, Iam testing it and trying to understand it. If it will work, I will mark it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are  **not returning anything** from timeToString function and also change **map** to **find** because map returns an array and since you haven't mentioned an else condition you will get value and undefined inside the array

If you used map without an else condition, then you would have got

`[ undefined , "10 seconds", undefined, undefined]`

Check the fixed code below

```
   let timeToString = (time: number) => {
       return Object.keys(timeObject).find((key) => {
            if (timeObject[key] === time) {
                   return timeObject[key]
         }
   })
```

**How does it work ?**

`Object.keys(timeObject)` will give you an array of keys like

`[ "On web close", "10 seconds", "8 hours", " 12 hours"]`

You can then use all the array methods to calculate your desired result.

Lastly you need to return that result from the function.